# How to display RelativeLayout and ImageView on Android?

Tags: android

I have added a RelativeLayout and ImageView dynamically, but it's not displaying in the emulator when I run the application. Why?

My code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);         
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.freshface_mmm);
    relativeLayout.addView(iv,lp);
```

Comment: where have you added/displayed this RelativeLayout? Code pls

Comment: I added it in My activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the relative layout to the activity using:

```
    setContentView(view, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using  this if you want to add view:

`ViewGroup relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());`

Answer (score 0):

set ImageView position to center,left,bottom etc on its parent..